# Calculate percentage change between values of column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some price indices across 5 years, from 2017 to 2021. It looks like this:

| Country | Industry | Year | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | Agriculture | 2017 | 83 |
| US | Agriculture | 2018 | 97.2 |
| US | Agriculture | 2019 | 100 |
| US | Agriculture | 2020 | 112 |
| US | Agriculture | 2021 | 108 |
| Japan | Mining | 2017 | 88 |
| Japan | Mining | 2018 | 93 |
| Japan | Mining | 2019 | 100 |
| Japan | Mining | 2020 | 104 |
| Japan | Mining | 2021 | 112 |

My base year is 2019, hence the Index for every row tagged with 2019 is 100. Everything else moves up or down. I want to generate another column called `Percentage_Change` showing the year on year change starting from 2019 as the base year.

I tried using the `pd.series.pct_change` function, however, that calculates the year on year percentage change starting with 2017 and it generates an `NaN` value for all rows where the year is 2017, instead of 2019 which should be the base year.

I want the output to look like this:

| Country | Industry | Year | Index | Percentage_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | Mining | 2017 | 88 | -5.37% |
| Japan | Mining | 2018 | 93 | -7% |
| Japan | Mining | 2019 | 100 | 0 |
| Japan | Mining | 2020 | 104 | 4% |
| Japan | Mining | 2021 | 112 | 7.69% |

The `percentage_change` for Japan between 2021 and 2020 is (112-104)/104 = 7.69%, the difference between 2020 and 2019 is (104-100)/100 = 4%, the difference between 2018 and 2019 is (93-100)/100 = -7%, the difference between 2017 and 2018 is (88-93)/93 = -5.37%

Is there any other way of calculating % change in pandas?

Comment: the `pct_change` is relative to the previous value, so there is no global reference. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pct_change` is computing a change **relative to the previous value** (which is why 2017 is NaN), and this doesn't seem to be what you want. If you want to compute a percentage change **relative to 2019**, as 2019 is already normalized to 100, simply subtract 100:

```
df['Percentage_Change'] = df['Index'].sub(100)
```

output:

```
  Country     Industry  Year  Index  Percentage_Change
0      US  Agriculture  2017   83.0              -17.0
1      US  Agriculture  2018   97.2               -2.8
2      US  Agriculture  2019  100.0                0.0
3      US  Agriculture  2020  112.0               12.0
4      US  Agriculture  2021  108.0                8.0
5   Japan       Mining  2017   88.0              -12.0
6   Japan       Mining  2018   93.0               -7.0
7   Japan       Mining  2019  100.0                0.0
8   Japan       Mining  2020  104.0                4.0
9   Japan       Mining  2021  112.0               12.0
```

##### bidirectional `pct_change`

If you want a bidirectional `pct_change` "centered" on 100, you can use masks to compute the `pct_change` both ways:

```
df['Percentage_Change'] = (df
 .assign(ref=df['Year'].eq(2019))
 .groupby(['Country', 'Industry'], group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g: g['Index'].where(g['ref'].cummax()).pct_change()
                  .fillna(g['Index'][::-1].pct_change().mask(g['ref'].cummax(), 0))
       )
)
```

output:

```
  Country     Industry  Year  Index  Percentage_Change
0      US  Agriculture  2017   83.0          -0.146091
1      US  Agriculture  2018   97.2          -0.028000
2      US  Agriculture  2019  100.0           0.000000
3      US  Agriculture  2020  112.0           0.120000
4      US  Agriculture  2021  108.0          -0.035714
5   Japan       Mining  2017   88.0          -0.053763
6   Japan       Mining  2018   93.0          -0.070000
7   Japan       Mining  2019  100.0           0.000000
8   Japan       Mining  2020  104.0           0.040000
9   Japan       Mining  2021  112.0           0.076923
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    x1=dd.query("Year==2019").index.values[0]
    return pd.concat([dd.loc[:x1,'Index'][::-1].pct_change()
                         ,dd.loc[x1:,'Index'].pct_change()])\
                .fillna(0).iloc[1:].sort_index()

df1.assign(Percentage_change=df1.groupby('Country').apply(function1).droplevel(0))

        
         Country     Industry  Year  Index  Percentage_change
0      US  Agriculture  2017   83.0          -0.146091
1      US  Agriculture  2018   97.2          -0.028000
2      US  Agriculture  2019  100.0           0.000000
3      US  Agriculture  2020  112.0           0.120000
4      US  Agriculture  2021  108.0          -0.035714
5   Japan       Mining  2017   88.0          -0.053763
6   Japan       Mining  2018   93.0          -0.070000
7   Japan       Mining  2019  100.0           0.000000
8   Japan       Mining  2020  104.0           0.040000
9   Japan       Mining  2021  112.0           0.076923
```